# PHP loop through query, first row

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I'm trying to output something special with the first row but it seems to output on every row, here is the code im using:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat WHERE id > '".$_GET["latest"]."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 20");
$number = mysql_num_rows($query);
$i = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

echo "<div class='babble' style='width:130px;overflow:hidden;margin:auto;'><a href=\"javascript:ajaxpage('user_profile.php?game=1&ajax=1&user=".$row['author']."', 'content');\" style=\"cursor:pointer;\"><font color=#ff4355><b>".$row['author']."</b></font></a><font color=#ff4355>:</font></b> ".$row['babble']."</div>";
   if($i = 1)
   {
       echo "<script type='text/javascript'>newestid=".$row['id']."</script>";
$i = 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the [comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) `==`, not the [assignment operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) `=` in your `if` statement.

```
if ($i == 1)
```